# Problem when trying to get Contracts Group ~ Unknown URL content://com.android.contacts

Tags: android, android-sdk-2.1

Problem when trying to get **Contracts Group**

```
Uri contacts = ContactsContract.AUTHORITY_URI;
  //Log.v("23",contacts.toString());
  // Make the query.
  Cursor managedCursor = act.managedQuery(contacts, projection, // Which
    // columns
    // to
    // return
    null, // Which rows to return (all rows)
    null // Selection arguments (none)
    // Put the results in ascending order by name
    , ContactsContract.Groups.TITLE + " ASC"
    );
```

Having:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS"></uses-permission>
```

I get 
`ERROR/DatabaseUtils(198): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URL content://com.android.contacts`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You using wrong `Uri` try `ContactsContract.Groups.CONTENT_URI` Work with contacts groups is pretty tricky from my point of view so read documentation carefully

Answer (score 1):

Yes, wrong URI.  Here's an example to find by name (from http://www.androidref.com/#MapLocation):

```
//
//  Find contact based on name.
//
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
Cursor cursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null,
    "DISPLAY_NAME = '" + NAME + "'", null, null);
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    String contactId =
        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
...
```

Jay